# Time formatting in Activity Monitor

Tags: macos, activity-monitor, formatting, time

What's the time formatting in the CPU Time column?

[image]

so for example 1:07.75

Is it hh:mm.ss?
or is it 1min 7sec 75ms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it were h:m:s there would be a colon before the seconds, but it can't be seconds because in your screenshot there are 75 of them. Neither is it milliseconds since there  are only 2 digits. It's 75 hundredths of a second.

Picture showing longer-running processes, more clearly indicating hh:mm:ss.ss/100

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Respectfully, I am not sure this was answered. You wrote:

"....more clearly indicating hh:mm:ss.ss/100", and your logic is understandable. But, on my view of Activity Monitor, it is clearly showing values longer that the amount of time a particular app (or process) has been active. I even did a test on it, by firing up a few things (separately of course).
This makes me think that that first value could be days?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/317788)

Comment: I'm open to what you're saying, but then if my response to the above was the same (this didn't answer the question). He wrote, "... indicating...", so what should we do when we see a post with no answer?